# pytmx: issue trying to get the correct texture rectangle for sprite for objetcs on map

Tags: tiles, maps, python, sfml

:D Hello :D

I am currently developing a game engine. I'm using maps designed with Tiled and I placed several objects on a test map to develop the feature of loading objects as sprites/entities and I'm not able to get the correct texture rectangle for certain `GID` (with correct, I mean the chunk of image that I place as an object on the map), even thought that I'm looking for such `GID`s on the same place that I look for pattern tiles. anyway, I have two screenshots to illustrate.

Where I am right now:
[bad http://ompldr.org/vaGg4eA/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202013-02-15%2017:05:51.png](http://ompldr.org/vaGg4eA/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202013-02-15%2017:05:51.png)

What I want to achieve:
[good http://ompldr.org/vaGg5MA/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202013-02-15%2017:20:08.png](http://ompldr.org/vaGg5MA/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202013-02-15%2017:20:08.png)

There is the relevant source code:

```
def loadmap(self, mapfilepath=None):
    """ Load the map of the corresponding scene.

    Not need to implement this method.
    All map files must be read in
    tmx format, Tiled Map Editor Software
    http://www.mapeditor.org/"""
    if mapfilepath:
        self.__tmxmapfile = common.settings.joinpaths(
            common.settings.getrootfolder(),
                                        "maps", mapfilepath)
        self.tmxmapdata = tmxloader.load_tmx(self.__tmxmapfile)

        heightlist = []
        widthlist = []
        tilesets = []

        # These list of vertexarrays carry only visible vertices,
        # By layer.
        self.__vertexarraytodraw = []
        for i in xrange(0, len(self.tmxmapdata.tilelayers)):
            self.__vertexarraytodraw.append(
                sfml.VertexArray(sfml.PrimitiveType.QUADS))

        # Add a list of empty lists to place sprites
        # Each empty list represents a layer.
        self.sprites = []
        for i in xrange(0, len(self.tmxmapdata.tilelayers)):
            self.sprites.append([])

        objgid = []
        for gid in self.tmxmapdata.getObjects():
            # Registers the actual GID.
            rgid = self.tmxmapdata.registerGID(gid.gid)
            if rgid not in objgid and rgid != 0:
                # The returned GID is the GID used internally by pytmx
                objgid.append(rgid)
        logging.info("GIDs de objetos: {0}".format(objgid))

        logging.info("Cargando las baldosas del escenario...")
        # Load all the tiles from the set of tiles
        # Based on code written by bitcraft.
        self.tmxmapdata.images = [0] * self.tmxmapdata.maxgid

        for firstgid, tile in sorted((tile.firstgid, tile) for tile in \
                                  self.tmxmapdata.tilesets):
            filename = os.path.basename(tile.source)
            tilesets.append(
                media.loadimg("maps/tilesets/{0}".format(filename)))

            w, h = tilesets[-1].size
            widthlist.append(w)
            heightlist.append(h)
            totalheight = sum(heightlist[1:], 0)
            real_gid = tile.firstgid - 1
            logging.debug("tile.firstgid: {0}".format(
                    tile.firstgid))

            tilewidth = tile.tilewidth + tile.spacing
            tileheight = tile.tileheight + tile.spacing

            # some tileset images may be slightly larger than the tile area
            # ie: may include a banner, copyright, ect.
            # this compensates for that
            width = ((int((w - tile.margin * 2) + tile.spacing) / tilewidth) \
                     * tilewidth) - tile.spacing
            height = ((int((h - tile.margin * 2) + tile.spacing) / tileheight) \
                      * tileheight) - tile.spacing

            # using product avoids the overhead of nested loops
            p = product(xrange(tile.margin, height+tile.margin, tileheight),
                        xrange(tile.margin, width+tile.margin, tilewidth))

            for (y, x) in p:
                real_gid += 1

                gids = self.tmxmapdata.mapGID(real_gid)
                quad = None

                # This GID is used somewhere in the scene?
                if gids and gids[0][0] in objgid:
                    # This GID belongs to an object that will be drawn
                    # Within the scenario.

                    texpos = sfml.Vector2(float(x), float(y + totalheight))
                    texsize = sfml.Vector2(tilewidth, tileheight)
                    quad = sfml.Rectangle(texpos, texsize)
                    # sfml.Rectangle(
                    #     (x, y + totalheight),
                    #     (tilewidth,
                    #      totalheight + tileheight))
                elif gids:
                    # This GID belongs to a tile.
                    v1 = sfml.Vertex((0, 0), None, sfml.Vector2(
                            float(x), float(y + totalheight)))
                    v2 = sfml.Vertex((0, 0), None, sfml.Vector2(
                            v1.tex_coords.x + tilewidth,
                            v1.tex_coords.y))
                    v3 = sfml.Vertex((0, 0), None, sfml.Vector2(
                            v1.tex_coords.x + tilewidth,
                            v1.tex_coords.y + tileheight))
                    v4 = sfml.Vertex((0, 0), None, sfml.Vector2(
                            v1.tex_coords.x,
                            v1.tex_coords.y + tileheight))
                    quad = (v1, v2, v3, v4,)

                elif gids == []:
                    # This GID is not used for anything.
                    continue

                # Stores the object, no matters if a tuple with vertexs 
                # or a sfml's rectangle
                for gid, flag in gids:
                    logging.debug("real_gid: {0}, gid:"
                                  " {1}, flag: {2}".format(real_gid,
                                                           gid, flag))
                    self.tmxmapdata.images[gid] = quad
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and as I should have guessed, this is related to a bug on pytmx, more details here: https://github.com/bitcraft/PyTMX/issues/9#issuecomment-13922180